# Xcode 3.2.5 Cocoa project modifies linked 3rd party dylib. Why?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, dylib

I'm linking a 3rd party dylib into a cocoa project.

I arrange for Xcode to copy it into the Frameworks directory of the app.

But when I cmp the original dylib with the dylib in Frameworks I discover the 3rd party dylib has been modified. I have some old Xcode cocoa projects which don't do this, i.e. the dylib in Frameworks is the same as the original.

I've tried modifying the Xcode projects to isolate what is causing the dylib to be modified but so far no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could Xcode be changing the install_path of the dylib to ensure it can be loaded from the Frameworks directory? I wouldn't expect Xcode to make any changes at all, but that's the only reasonable thing I can think of.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the suggestion.  Maybe that is it however there are 2 things which make me think not:

Comment: Oops got cut off.  I already set the install_path before building my project.  Also if I take the old project which doesn't modify the dylib and run it (with the new XCode) it doesn't modify the dylib.

Comment: mipadi,  I don't know how the dylib is modified.  I only can tell that it is modified by using cmp to compare it with the original version.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in the Target Build Settings under the Deployment heading to make sure `Strip Debug Symbols During Copy` is unchecked.

[image]

Then Clean All, and rebuild.